# The ^ gets doubled when sending string as parameter to function in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, escaping

This is my code:

```
set var1="`netsh int ipv4 show interface ^| findstr /I Network`"

call:GetEles %var1%
goto:eof

:GetEles
for /F "tokens=1 usebackq" %%F IN (%~1) do echo %%F
goto:eof
```

When I check the command while it is running, the `^` becomes doubled inside function `:GetEles`:

```
for /F "token=1 usebackq" %%F IN (`netsh int ipv4 show interface ^^| findstr /I Network`) do echo %%F
```

That doubled `^` makes my script failing, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others already described, this is a nasty "feature" of the [`call` command](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html).

There are several options to work around that:

1. Simply undo the caret doubling in the sub-routine:

   ```cmd
   @echo off
   set "VAR=caret^symbol"
   call :SUB "%VAR%"
   exit /B

   :SUB
       set "ARG=%~1"
       echo Argument: "%ARG:^^=^%"
       exit /B
   ```
2. `call` introduces a second parsing phase, so let the second one expand the variable:

   ```cmd
   @echo off
   set "VAR=caret^symbol"
   call :SUB "%%VAR%%"
   exit /B

   :SUB
       echo Argument: "%~1"
       exit /B
   ```
3. Pass the value by reference (so the variable name) rather than by value:

   ```cmd
   @echo off
   set "VAR=caret^symbol"
   call :SUB VAR
   exit /B

   :SUB
       setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
       echo Argument: "!%~1!"
       endlocal
       exit /B
   ```
4. Do not pass the variable value to the sub-routine, read the (global) variable there instead:

   ```cmd
   @echo off
   set "VAR=caret^symbol"
   call :SUB
   exit /B

   :SUB
       echo Argument: "%VAR%"
       exit /B
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Read [Buggy behaviour when using CALL](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html):

> Redirection with `&` `|` `<>` does not work as expected.
>
> If the CALL command contains a caret character within a quoted string
>   `"test^ing"`, **the carets will be doubled**.

Try following code snippet:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

set "var1=`netsh int ipv4 show interface ^| findstr /I "Network"`"

call:GetEles "%var1%"
goto:eof

:GetEles
echo variable  "%var1%"
echo parameter "%~1"
for /F "tokens=1 usebackq" %%F IN (%var1%) do echo %%F
goto:eof
```

**Output**:

```
d:\bat> D:\bat\SO\41769803.bat

variable  "`netsh int ipv4 show interface ^| findstr /I "Network"`"
parameter "`netsh int ipv4 show interface ^^| findstr /I "Network"`"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this, *(the `call` will not expand the `%var1%` to a point which will expose the poison character)*.

```
set "var1='netsh int ipv4 show interface ^| findstr /I Network'"

call:GetEles "%%var1%%"
goto:eof

:GetEles
for /F %%F IN (%~1) do echo %%F
goto:eof
```

*You will note that `tokens=1` wasn't needed and neither was `usebackq`*

Comment: +1, but `call` *does* expand the `%var1%` variable as this command initiates a second parsing phase; the `%~1` argument in the reference is expanded once only; proof: `call echo %%var1%%`, which returns the value of `var1` (if I were wrong, it would expand to `%var1%` literally)...

Comment: I may not have explained my point technically but it remains correct for the purpose of my answer, _updated my answer accordingly_.